# Mouse freezes when a second mouse is plugged in

Tags: usb, mouse

I use a wireless Logitech trackball for RSI reasons.  My wife uses a random dell usb mouse because she hates the trackball.  We have a single Mac mini and use fast user switching to change accounts.

On both accounts, the trackball stops tracking.  It'll move the cursor for a while and then stop mid-motion.  The buttons still work.

On the login window, the mouse works.  When I log in from there, it works for up to a minute.  Then it dies again.

I had no issues with this mouse on my previous machine (linux) and the issue started immediately when I switched to this mac.

Equipment:  2014 Mac Mini running Sierra.  Logitech m570 trackball.  Generic dell usb other mouse.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your Mac model, OS version, and trackball model.

Answer (score 1):

I might have fixed this.  Not sure yet, but it's been usable for a whole 10 minutes which is a new record.

The fix?  I shuffled usbs until I found a permutation that works.  Didn't think that would be a problem in 2017, but here we are.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen too, also where I could move the mouse but not click. I always had to turn off the connected mouse, then turn it back on and that seemed to fix the problem for me.

Comment: I've tried turning it off, unplugging it, etc.  No luck so far.